# SQL use max date from one table in where statement of another

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's the business problem I'm trying to solve.  We have a sales table that updates weekly based on invoicing.  We also have a daily sales table that I want select so it's just transactions since the last refresh of the weekly sales table.

```
daily_sales.invoice_date > weekly_sales.invoice_date
```

I need to get the `MAX` date from the weekly sales table and then use to filter the daily sales data I'm pulling in a new SQL job.  Source tables are in oracle.  I'm a SQL rookie at best... any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Something like:

```
Select  a. SDKCOO "Order Company", a. SDDOCO "Order Number", a. SDDCTO "Order Type", a.SDIVD “Invoice Date”, a.SDAEXP "Sales"
from    daily_sales a, weekly_sales b where a.SDIVD > b.DSIVD
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's quite enough information here to define the solution. How about adding the table designs fro both `daily_sales` and `weekly_sales`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the MAX date from the weekly sales table and then use to
>   filter the daily sales

```
select sdkcoo , sddoco, sddcto, sdivd, sdaexp 
  from daily_sales
  where sdivd > (select max(dsivd) from weekly_sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what you want to achive but depending on my understanding do you want something like this:

```
  Select  a. SDKCOO "Order Company", a. SDDOCO "Order Number", a. SDDCTO "Order Type", a.SDIVD “Invoice Date”, a.SDAEXP "Sales", b.MAX(DATE)
    from    daily_sales a CROSS JOIN weekly_sales b where a.SDIVD > b.DSIVD
    group by a. SDKCOO , a. SDDOCO , a. SDDCTO , a.SDIVD , a.SDAEXP
```

Comment: This is going to use a cross join between `a` and `b`.  Are you certain that's right?

Comment: yes i have edited my answer but still i didnt understood what OP wants to achive as his question is unclear and missing data